# How to use foreign key in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql

In structure database there are two tables:

```
Courier | Order
```

The table `Order` has field: `courier_id`. This if foreign key to table `Courier`.

By default it should be NULL(here attention).

When courier accept order then filed `courier_id` is changed on id of courier.

But when courier reject this order, I should set NULL ot zero to field. I know this is not possible for foreign key.

What I should do in this case?

Comment: "I know this is not possible for foreigh key."  What you "know" is wrong.  Foreign keys can be `NULL`, unless another constraint prevents that.

Comment: When I try to set NULL I get Mysql error: `Foreign keys can be NULL, unless another constraint prevents that.`

Comment: I assume that the best way to create separated table with values who accepted or refused orders?

Comment: No, its probably not

Comment: You need to have a good think about how you store your data

Comment: In the simplest way I have field in table, who accepted this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are trying to achieve two use cases here.

1. Order assignment to a Courier.
2. Order status flow.

Ideally these two should represented in two columns. Same like Courier your Order table should have a Status column and based on the situation it should have some value like PENDING, ASSIGNED, REJECTED, DELIVERED etc. I think that is more cleaner than trying to handle different use cases from a single data point.

Answer (score 0):

Take it easy, set a default value for 'Not curier', it's better than null.

if you have a Couriers table like this: [courier_id], [courier_name], [...]

the first record could be: [0],[No courier assigned],[...]

this allow you to ask for orders whithout courier assigned, avoiding to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

and you can set a default field value of [0] for new records.

Comment: What is default value? If I set zero, it will find related row in table `Courier` because this is foreign key.

Comment: Seem you method is as crutch

Comment: a crutch? you can use a constraint to set a dafault value for all new records

Comment: and by the way, you can use null with foreingen keys in mysql

Comment: mcNets is correct - I would caution against using a null value to mean something! This is poor DB design. A null in the courier field does not mean no courier. It means a value is not available or not entered. A better, more stable design is to have a record in courier table named "no courier" and make that the default value for all orders, until the courier is set to a "real" courier.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql allow keep nullable field in foreign key constraint. Make sure you define `courier_id` as nullable. See example below.

```
CREATE TABLE `couriers` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `orders` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `courier_id` INT NULL , `product_id` INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD INDEX(`courier_id`);
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_courier` FOREIGN KEY (`courier_id`) REFERENCES `couriers`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```